# How to tackle timeout error in Modbus TCP

Tags: modbus, modbus-tcp

I am working on a Modbus client in 'C'.

I don't have deep knowledge about Modbus, and I am facing an issue with the implementation.

The **ReadCoil** function code work fine but many times I get Request Timeout error.
I have used the '*interframe_delay*' = 10ms and '*request_timeout*' = 2 sec as configuration parameters.
I have tried multiple combinations of the above two config parameters, yet I am unable to find a solution.
Also in the **ReadCoil** function I try to read approx 500 coils in one request.
I tried reading with quantity = 1, yet the issue is observed sometimes.

Does this have anything to do with the slave device ?

Do we need to have same config for slave devices as well ?

Any suggestion on how I can tackle this problem ?

Comment: Just retry. Network problems happen from time to time